# What is the best way to manage contacts in Office 365 for a company of 80-100?

Tags: powershell, outlook, ms-office, exchange-server, office365

problem: the GAL does not show up as contacts on user's iphones.

real world example: bob calls sam. sam doesn't know who the number is because the GAL are not synced as contacts in his iphone.

now i know that you can search the GAL from the email side of the phone. i know that you can manually add all the users in the GAL to your contacts in Outlook which will sync to your phone. but this is not a good enough solution because if anything changes in the GAL your info is out of date. and i also do not trust users to be able to follow instructions to add people from the GAL to their contacts.

therefore, is there anything that can be done to make this automatically happen? all the solutions out there require either an onsite exchange server or changing our hosting. the company is currently hosted by microsoft through the office 365 licensing. i would settle for a solution that has to be done per computer (like a script or something that runs once a week on a user's machine) but i would really like something that can be done on the office 365 side. i cannot believe this does not exist.

Comment: Do you want to manage this list centrally, or by each user?

Comment: i edited the main comment with better explanation

Answer (score 0):

There is some information (although often conflicting) stating that if you use ActiveSync on the iPhone it will sync the iPhone to your GAL on Office 365 but I have had mixed results.  Something that will definitely work that will also let your users open Non-person accounts would be the OWA app for iOS. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/owa-for-iphone/id659503543?mt=8